# How can I map between entity model with simple properties and viewmodel with a List<said properties>?

Tags: c#, automapper

How can I map `List<this entity model>`:

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

... and this viewmodel (The entity class property `Title` should not map to the viewmodel property `Title`, but to `Categories.Title`):

```
public class ViewModelProductCategories
{
    public List<ViewModelProductCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }// Used to create new category the Index view
    // User Interface parameter switches:
    public bool CanCreateCategory { get; set; }
    public bool CanCreateProduct { get; set; }
}
```

This is the viewmodel referenced by `ViewModelProductCategories`. It is important that I also get the navigational properties when I map:

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    // Nav.props:
    public List<ViewModelFrontPageProduct> FrontPageProducts { get; set; }
    public ViewModelProductCategory ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public ViewModelProductCategories Children { get; set; }
    public List<ViewModelProduct> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This was my old mapping, which mapped directly to `ViewModelProductCategory`:

```
CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategory>()
            .ForMember(dst => dst.Products, opt => opt.MapFrom(
                src => src.ProductInCategory.Select(pc => pc.Product)));
```

Here I got access to `Products`, via `ProductInCategory` in each category. I still need that, but the categories will now be in a `List`.

Comment: From where do you want to map? From a single class to 1 item in the list?

Comment: @Icepickle Haha, I got it! I can use `List<ProductCategory` as source. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unterstand your question correctly, you want to pass a single `ProductCategory` to Automapper and get a `ViewModelProductCategories` with a single entry in the `Categories` collection.

1) Define a mapping `ProductCategory` -> `ViewModelProductCategory`

```
CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategory>();
```

2) Use this mapping to resolve the collection in `ViewModelProductCategories`

```
CreateMap<ProductCategory, ViewModelProductCategories>()
    .ForMember(vm => vm.Categories, 
               o => o.ResolveUsing(src => Mapper.Map<List<ViewModelProductCategory>>(src))
    );
```

This assumes that the mapping `ProductCategory` -> `ViewModelProductCategory` is configured for the static Automapper instance. Note that Automapper will create collections automatically if he knows how to map the elements.

Usage:

```
var cat = new ProductCategory();
ViewModelProductCategories vm = Mapper.Map<ViewModelProductCategories>(cat);
```

Comment: I'm not even sure if I understand my question correctly. I want to map between a `List<ProductCategory>` and the property `Categories ` in `ViewModelProductCategories`, and I also need some additional properties along side the list. I will update my question to show all the properties I need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have opted for an alternative approach to the whole problem. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoMapper or you can just `Project`/`Select` into your `ViewModals`

```
var productCategories = context.Where(<my filter>)
               .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
               .Select(x => new ViewModelProductCategory()
                 {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Title = x.Title,
                    SortOrder = x.SortOrder, 
                    ParentId = x.ParentId
                 }); 

var viewModelProductCategories  = new ViewModelProductCategories()
                {
                   Categories  = productCategories 
                   ...
                   // other shenanigans here  
                };
```